# Testing a Json web service Post operation on Internet explorer

Tags: json, web-services, internet-explorer

I know I can test POST web service operations on fiddler, but I want to be able to test directly on IE. How do I do a post on a RESTful service call, passing in a JSON object using only IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options:

- The address bar does a GET, so the easiest way to do a POST is with script in an html file on disk.
- If you don't want to use a separate file, you can use the F12 debugger and use the console.
- You said no Fiddler, but jsFiddle.net works great on IE.

For the script itself:

- If you can use jQuery: $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "http://yoururl.com", data: data });
- If you only want to use what script is supported natively by IE, use one of the built in HTTP objects: http://blog.mgechev.com/2011/07/21/ajax-jquery-beginners/

Comment: I am trying to use the F12 debugger and write in the Console. But I get the following error "Object doesn't support property or method 'ajax'". Any idea what causes this? I am on IE version 11